# A way to Pass a Variable to a Networked path Batch file and Execute

Tags: windows, batch-file, psexec

Going to lay this out the best I can and see if someone here can help me out a bit.

Here is my Code .bat on the Remote Server.

```
echo off
title SystemPlatzAll
set /p input=
findstr %input% SysPlatzAll.log >> Result.txt
%SystemRoot%\explorer.exe "Result.txt"
pause
```

What im trying to achieve is sending the **%input%** across the network to this batch file then excute and in return have the file save to the computer it is on. To which then the user will get the file opened from a shared folder i have on the drive.
can I use PsExec to send this over or is there another way?

I can get the .bat to execute with the following.

```
psexec \\HIFRP010.ad.foo.com -u hoem\hoemfooprod -p !foounit123 -e -h -accepteula -i 0 -d F:\Public\Logfiles\Systemplatz\foo\SystemPlatzBackup1.1\Final\NextTest.bat
pause
```

The above code will execute the Program.

But I want to know how or if it is possible to instead send %input% from one .bat to another.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible.  I am not familiar with psexec, but you may be able to encapsulate the last parameter in doublequotes as is common on windows and pass input params directly on the command line.  I do this using runas fairly often.

```
 "F:\Public\Logfiles\Systemplatz\foo\SystemPlatzBackup1.1\Final\NextTest.bat paramFoo paramBar"
```

Comment: I will check this out when I get into work thank you!